# Why https connections are so slow when debugging (stepping over) in Java?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, networking

I'm trying to debug some problems with my Java code, which establishes a http/https connection. I'm wondering why the connection gets ridiculously slow (more than one minute for downloading a small web page) when debugging, even when stepping-over the method which does the network work. And if there is some remedy.

Below I post an example (you can change `https:` to `http:` , and try debugging this from Eclipse pressing `F11` - for stepping, place a breakpoint in the first `main()` statement, and press `F6` when it pauses there.

My results (time in milliseconds) :

```
                        conn time   total time
http  (not stepping)        60           350
http  (stepping over)     1100          1500
https (not stepping)       570          1300
https (stepping over)    21000         83000
```

---

Edit: after disabling `Show method result after a step operation` option (the remedy aptly suggested by howlger's answer), the times become *much* more reasonable (about one-tenth for https).

```
http  (stepping over 2)     150           450
https (stepping over 2)    2000          7000
```

---

My scenario: Java 8 (1.8.0_121-b13) , 64 bits, Win-7, Eclipse Photon (also experienced with Oxygen).

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class TestConn {

    public static void downloadFromUrl(final URL url) throws IOException {
        long t0 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        System.out.println("conn msecs: " +
              (System.currentTimeMillis() - t0) + " url=" + url);
        System.out.println("=====================================");
        try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8))) {
            String line;
            int cont = 0;
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                if (cont++ < 4)
                    System.out.println(line);
            } 
            if(cont >=4) 
                System.out.printf("== total lines: %d (%d skipped)\n",cont,cont-4);
            System.out.println("==============done=======================");
        } 
    }

    public static void testConn(String urls) {
        try {
            long t0 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            downloadFromUrl(new URL(urls));
            System.out.println("Done , total time msecs: " + 
              (System.currentTimeMillis() - t0));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        testConn("https://www.example.com/"); // breakpoint here, step-over with F6
        System.out.println("bye");
    }
}
```

Comment: You aren't measuring what you think you are. Once a connection is established, the socket is held open; so it only has to connect once. Depending on the order of your tests, the **first** one is going to be slow. And then everything after that is faster. Which is to say your debugger isn't the root cause of the slow down.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch : My measures are done in differnt runs, hence they are different JVM instances, no chance of socket reuse. Furthermore, my results don't depend on the order. And in any case,  87 seconds to download a webpage, even from the coldest state, is absurd.

Comment: 1) When you connect a debug agent and set breakpoints, the JVM deoptimizes the code.  This is liable to make it a lot slower. 2) I doubt that the Java team puts in a great deal of effort to make code run fast while being debugged.  Why?  Because most Java users don't care, and it is bad engineering to spend dev effort on things that people don't care about. 3) "Absurd" is your **opinion**.  There is no scientific measure of "absurdity".

Comment: 4) If you really care .... then download OpenJDK and start investigating the JVM to figure out why this is slow.  Once you have found the cause(s), develop patches to fix them and submit them to the OpenJDK team in the standard way.

Comment: Apart from 4) there is no remedy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's why in ***Window > Preferences: Java > Debug*** there is the preference ***Show method result after a step operation (if supported by the VM; maybe slow)***.

Since Eclipse 2018-09 (4.9) a timeout (7 seconds by defaults) can be set for that:

- [Eclipse 4.9 - New and Noteworthy - Timeout for result of step operation](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.9/jdt.php#step-result-timeout)
- [Short video of this new feature](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rW6VRX1lqk0&t=170s)

Comment: Well, _this_ was useful. Thanks.